# Open source queuing theory algorithms in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, math, statistics, queue

I need to write a program to analyze the performance of computer systems and networks using queuing theory (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queueing_theory). I was wondering if there is an open source Java library implementing the various algorithms of queuing theory that can make my task easier.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article you've referenced has a link [to the JMT Java Modelling Tools Simulator](http://jmt.sourceforge.net/JSIMg.html) at the bottom

Comment: Thanks, I did not notice that while linking it. :)